# Exception in registering FFEngine

Tags: ios, rtmp, video-player

I am using [FFEngine](https://github.com/xiewei-wayne/FFEngine.framework) for playing video via rtmp. I am getting the following exception:

> __NSCFString objectFromJSONString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa039d80 on the line
>   RegisterFFEngine(@"yQ2oiBQRbXoo35veDico9ggF4ARFxRdjq3yiIvBltwIPe/SgphrthjEVCzt6mtAfejcyM1fkbDdY+wE8j7oeJLK+u1KEO7IgfEDQ+KrnsNc=")

I don't know whether the registration key is incorrect or there is some other issue. Need some help.

Comment: I have received the answer from the vendor. A JSON Parser Framework needs to be included in the file as well as in the compile sources. I have taken json parser framework from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993118/json-library-for-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

when you use **FFEngine** framework , you have to add “-ObjC” in your project. below is the simple step add to “-ObjC” in your project :

1) Select the project file from the project navigator on the far left side of the window.

2) Select the target for where you want to add the linker flag.

3) Select the “Build Settings” tab

4) Choose “All” to show all Build Settings.

5) Scroll down to the “Linking” section, and double-click to the right of where it says “Other Linking Flags”.

6) A box will appear, Click on the “+” button to add a new linker flag.

7) Type “-ObjC” (no quotes) and press enter.

when you add **-ObjC** then after error will solved.